# Webpage loading in internet explorer problem?

Tags: html, css, xml

Using CSS Style Sheet, HTML, XML

When i run my website, my page was properly displaying in the firefox, but the page was not properly displaying in the internet explorer.

Most of the people using only the internet explorer, but why my web page is not properly loading in the internet explorer.

I have to change the setting of internet explorer?

How to solve this problem.

Comment: @Doug - Link to your site means?

Comment: @Gopal, sorry. Can you post a link to your site? Internet Explorer almost *never* looks the same as the other browsers if you didn't take it into account while building. But what needs to be done to fix it, is best found out by viewing the site. If you can't share a link, go to http://browserlab.adobe.com and make screenshots in Firefox 3 and Internet Explorer 7 and update your answer to include links to those images.

Comment: we need either a link to the site or (better) the code/markup for the part that isn't displaying correctly.  Or a description of the problem.  something.

Comment: Welcome to the pain of web development. ;) Bookmark this invaluable resource: http://www.quirksmode.org/

Comment: It would help if the problem(s) were described deeply. Either that or the address of the website, in order to check the issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, without a link to your site it's hard to tell exactly what the problem is, but if it's a CSS problem in IE6 you could try using [the IE7-js library](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/), which will make IE6 fairly standards compliant. Also, you may want to look at [this resource](http://www.maratz.com/blog/archives/2005/06/16/essentials-of-css-hacking-for-internet-explorer/) for general help with CSS hacking in IE.